# Required module missing methods

Tags: sapui5, amd

Is it a bug from UI5 (1.60.2) or I am doing something wrong here?

```js
onSelectPreferredTreatment: function(event) {
  // ...
  const oDialog = new Dialog({/*...*/});
  oDialog.open();
},
```

> VM77446:1 Uncaught **TypeError: oDialog.open is not a function**
>     at eval (eval at onSelectPreferredTreatment (Preview.controller.js?eval:NaN), :1:9)
>     at f.onSelectPreferredTreatment (Preview.controller.js?eval:552)

[image: Full structure of oDialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the dependency list in your controller. The order of the required modules should reflect the order of available parameters of the callback function exactly.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller", // 1st
  "sap/m/Dialog", // 2nd
  // ...
], function(Controller/*1st*/, Dialog/*2nd, ...*/) {
  // ...
});
```

You might also have required some modules twice, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55289688/5846045

Comment: exactly was the reason, thanks. Unfortunately, there was one module introduced , but not included to the callback before (not by me) and I've added a Dialog on top of it, but it was therefore not in a correct order.